# SQL query in PHP only works outside function

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP snippet:

```
function getFacilities($testName, $dbAdapter) {
  $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM facilities_db WHERE facility_name = '$testName'";
  $result1 = $dbAdapter->query($sql1);

  $facility_details = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
  {
    $facility_details[] = $row;
  }
  return $facility_details;
}

$testName = "Abraham Moss Leisure";
$facility_data = getFacilities($testName, $mysqli);
```

The value of $testName is arbitrary just for testing purposes. This is the function from one of the answers, but my the only difference in my initial definition was not having $dbAdapter as a parameter.

Comment: Show us how you define your function!!

Comment: please post your whole function & how did you call the function with parameter.

Comment: Are you keeping the ' when using the params?

Comment: Show us how you're defining the function!

Comment: Also don't forget to check scope of all your variables with and without function!!

Comment: Edited the post so that it contains the whole function.

Comment: why people still use mysqli is past me but why not just use `foreach` ? like: `foreach ($dbAdapter->query($sql1) as $row) { [...] }`

Comment: That is not my problem. I only want that code snippet to work inside a function so I can call it with a parameter from jQuery, nothing else.

Comment: Everybody lies. Your posted snippet should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set $testName as a parameter, but also the adapter you are going to use to get the connection to your SGBD (here it's mysqli).

```
function getFacilities($testName, $dbAdapter) {
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM facilities_db WHERE facility_name = '$testName'";
    $result1 = $dbAdapter->query($sql1);

    $facility_details = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
      $facility_details[] = $row;
    }
    return $facility_details;
}
```

We need to pass `$testName` and `$mysqli` as your dbAdapter to the function. 
Thus, this is how we would call the function :

```
$facility_data = getFacilities($testName, $dbAdapter);
```

hope this'll help,

Comment: The array returned is still empty :(. If I call the function using a string instead of $testName for example, the same thing happens.

Comment: Yes. I just checked it without the function and it works like a charm.

Comment: Worked after defining $dbAdapter as a global variable with $mysqli value and only parsing the $testName (for whatever reason that is...). Thanks!

Comment: If `global` answer works for you - you must try to provide `$dbAdapter` instead of `$mysqli` to `getFacilities` call.

Comment: All right, I added the $dbAdapter parameter back and parsed it when calling the function after defining it as $mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

test query result:

```
print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
```

test `$mysqli` in function:

```
function get($testName, $adapter) { if (!isset($adapter)) echo 'no'; }
```

use static database connection:

```
class GlobalClass { public static $db = null; }

class Connection {
public $connection = null;
public function connect() {
    if ($connection == null)
        // operation
    $this->connection = 'obj';
}}


$db = new Connection();
$db->connect();
GlobalClass::$db = new Connection();
GlobalClass::$db->connect();
GlobalClass::$db->connection->query($sql);

function yourFunction($testName) {
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM facilities_db WHERE facility_name = '$testName'";

    $result1 = GlobalClass::$db->connection->query($sql1);

    $facility_details = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
      $facility_details[] = $row;
    }
    return $facility_details;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the database connection is already written and it works fine for everything else I have! Solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
    function getFacilities($testName) {
          global $dbAdapter;
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM facilities_db WHERE facility_name = '$testName'";
        $result1 = $dbAdapter->query($sql1);

        $facility_details = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
        {
          $facility_details[] = $row;
        }
        return $facility_details;
    }

$testName = "Abraham Moss Leisure";
$facility_data = getFacilities($testName);
```

declare the connection variable as global and pass the value for the $testname

Comment: Even though I don't know why, this worked. Thank you!

Comment: omg, please, no... Why php maintainers do not removed that `global` yet?

Comment: You shouldn't use global variables. It leads to very high technical debt.

Comment: why cant use global variable can you plz explain then how can use the connection variable inside the function

Comment: You should check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why.

Comment: I agree with not using global variables. It is difficult to maintain in the long term.

Comment: Solution is in the comments of the accepted answer.